# Recently I did an update on Kotlin version in intelliji and then don't no why I'm getting this error. Can anyone help me out

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea, jvm, intellij-plugin

I wild guess there's something to do with the syntax compatible with the latest kotlin version 1.4.30

How can I change my settings?

[image: compile errors]

Comment: Does full rebuild help? Please share full exception text and project to reproduce, if possible.

Comment: No, rebuild did not work. By the way I found out something but don't know how its related! when I omit the 22nd line in spice.kt file which consisting enum class(short single line code). Then the execution is normal. I don't know the reason and even the classes are independant. I wonder 8-[

Comment: This could be a compiler bug. Can you please share a project to reproduce?

Comment: thank you for the interest, problem solved :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is invalid - there is no `rgb` property in the `Color` class. That looks like intellij cached something and doens't want to give it up.

Please execute `Main Meme | File | Invalidate Caches / Restart | Invalidate and Restart`, it force the IDE to drop all system caches.